# Why doesn't my JS add an HTML class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been messing with this code for a while now, and I can't seem to make it work.  I made a `div` that is a green box and I want it to do my CSS transform when it is clicked on (by using JS to add a class), however that is not what it is doing right now.  What rookie mistake did I make with this one?

---

Here's my code:  There is also a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeff_arries/zn2nhbnt/14/)!

```js
function box() { document.getElementById('box')[0].setAttribute("class", "box_ready"); 
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #393;
}

#box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_ready {
    -webkit-animation: slide 2s;
            animation: slide 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(600px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(600px, 0px);
            transform: translate(600px, 0px);
            transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
  
}

/* Add WebKit when done*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="box" onclick="box()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your console, you have an error. FYI, `getElementById()` does **not** return an array

Comment: Fiddle and Code in the Question is different...

Comment: @Rayon Really?  How so?

Comment: In above snippet, You are using `getElementById` but in Fiddle, it is `getElementsByClassName`.... With `getElementsByClassName`, you need to mention the `index` of the element as it returns `NodeList`...

Comment: @Rayon Oh, yeah, I didn't notice that, updated my JSFiddle (and the link in the post)! Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/zn2nhbnt/17/

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle @Rayon!

Comment: @Jeff  your code is ok.. only do add javascript inside head element.  Please check jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/zn2nhbnt/24/

Comment: @SunnyS.M Thanks for your effort and JSFiddle!  I already figured it out!  But I will use some things in your fiddle!  Thank you!

Comment: hmmmm, I can see many experts answered and corrected you.... actually I was try to explain through your code.

Comment: @SunnyS.M I see!  Thanks for your explaining!  I'm sorry I didn't understand your comment!  Why put the JS in the `head`?  Loading issues? Or?

Comment: I put JS in head... so when browser rendered html and their associated function can be ready to use..

Comment: @SunnyS.M Yes, with this one I will!  But with some other scripts I don't them to slow down my page, that's all!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the existing class when you set the `class` HTML attribute. This removes the existing `box` class styling which makes the box disappear. You are also overriding the `translate` transform with the second `transform` CSS property.

Fixed JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn2nhbnt/20/

Edit: notice, I changed the translate and removed the prefixed properties for clarity.

Comment: Was this meant to be a comment reply to @rayon's comment?

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help fixing those issues!  I didn't really care about my transform sideways, but thanks for pointing it out anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work by removing the `[0]` from your function:

```
function box(){
    document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("class", "box_ready"); 
}
```

Remember, `getElementById()` returns one element, but `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements.

Also, although this may be obvious, you can only use `getElementById()` when the element has that as an ID. Ditto with `getElementByClassName()`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, please see this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeff_arries/zn2nhbnt/19/

Comment: Not familiar with JS fiddle, but I was having trouble getting the function to be loaded. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bf1nnfnf/

Comment: I saw your edit.  Thanks for all your time and energy on this project!  I appreciate what you contributed a lot!  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem dude :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should change to

`document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("class", "box_ready");`

`getElementById` returns only a single matching element, not an array, since a single document can not have an ID repeating more than once, according to [HTML standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id).

Comment: Damn you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

it is not `getElementsById` it should be `getElementById`